# Passing a variable into bindview of a cursor adapter in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-cursoradapter

I have a cursor adapter to populate a listview based on queries, I want to control the layout of listview by passing a variable in the adapter I do the following

```
public class QueryCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter{
View retView;
private DBHelper mHelper;
public QueryCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c,int QCase) {
    super(context, c, QCase);
}
```

Shouldnt put the variable in as well in the bindview like

```
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor,int qcase)
```

Why it says I need to declare class as abstract?

Is there any other way to control the layout based on the type of my queries in sqlite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [bindView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#bindView(android.view.View,%20android.content.Context,%20android.database.Cursor)) method - it can take only 3 defined params.
When you say your class `extends CursorAdapter`, you should implement this method, as it is declared as `abstract` in `CursorAdapter`. 
So, you should put only these 3 params in your implementation of `bindView`. When you put 4th param, system consider that it is not implementation of base method, but it's your own method. 
That's why you get message about declaring class as `abstract`, because you didn't implement base abstract method.

You can pass your needed param to constructor (as you do now) and save it to correspondent field of your class.
Then, in `bindView` method you can just use this field as you need.

**Upd.** Moreover, you can use as many params as you need - just create your own constructor, for example, `CursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, param1, param2 ... paramN)` and inside it don't forget to call base constructor `CursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c)`. Save your params into class fields and then use them in `bindView` and other methods as you need.

**Upd2.** Code example:

```
public class QueryCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter{
View retView;
private int myParam1, myParam2, myParam3;
private DBHelper mHelper;

public QueryCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int param1, int param2, int param3) {
    super(context, c);
    myParam1 = param1;
    myParam2 = param2;
    myParam3 = param3;
}
```

Then you can use these myParam1-2-3 anywhere in your adapter.

Comment: How I can save it to correspondent field of my class any example?

Comment: So in such a way I dont need to put parameter in bindview because it is already passed inside correct? thank you!

Comment: Yes, you are right, If I answered your question, please mark answer as correct (press checkmark), thx.